# Alter collation type of existing database

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a join across 2 databases (ver 2012 sp1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.User w
        INNER JOIN db1.dbo.UserAccounts mu ON mu.Email = w.email
```

but get

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between
>   "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal
>   to operation.

This bit of [MS documentation says](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175835.aspx) that this snippet would update these 2 databases so they use the same collation type:

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE db1
COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS ;
GO
ALTER DATABASE db2
COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS ;
GO
```

I can issue that command with no error

```
--Verify the collation setting.
SELECT name, collation_name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = N'db2' OR name = 'db1';
```

and see:

```
db1 Latin1_General_CI_AS
db2 Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

But still get the same error on my join attempt as prior to the collation 'change'.

Comment: You are just changing the default for new columns. You need to alter the collation on the existing columns.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

> To change the database collation

1. Connect to the Database Engine.
2. From the Standard bar, click New Query.
3. Copy and paste the following example into the query window and click
   Execute.

This example shows how to use the COLLATE clause in an ALTER DATABASE statement to change the collation name. Execute the SELECT statement to verify the change.

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE MyOptionsTest
COLLATE French_CI_AS ;
GO

--Verify the collation setting.
SELECT name, collation_name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = N'MyOptionsTest';
GO
```

[Change the Database Collation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175835.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Collation defined on Column Level takes precedence over database collation , Collation used in Query level takes precedence over column level collation.

In your case you have changed the database default collation but if there is a column with a different collation it will not effect that.

You will need to use explicit Collation in your query something like this ...

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.User w INNER JOIN db1.dbo.UserAccounts mu
ON ON mu.Email = w.email COLLATE database_default
```